# Loading appropriate Android app icon depending on dark or light theme

Tags: android, android-icons

I have an app icon with transparent background. I have 2 variants: black and white.

The issue I have found is that some android phone menu screens have a black background, while some others have a white background.

Therefore the issue I have is that my logo looks invisible on certain phones no matter which i pick.

How do I solve this problem?
Is there a way to use the dark or light variant depending on the theme?

Comment: Are you talking about notification icon?

Comment: No the actual app icon. I.e. the one you see on the menu screen to launch the app.